# Applying the Engle-Granger and the Johansen test to univariate multiple regression

Tags: cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have want to test the cointegration of interest rates in three time series: a group of small open economies, US, and Erozone. I use daily data, and assume that the small open economy has no impact on the other two series.

I know two tests for cointegration: the Engle-Granger test, and the Johansen test.

1. All examples I found using the Engle-Granger test are with the integration of two time series. But I have two regressor, i.e. three series. In principle I could estimate the regression with OLS and then test the residuals, or there is anything I did not consider?
2. All examples I found for Johansen are about multivariate regression, i.e. VARs. To chose the lag of the Johansen test they estimate a VAR and then use the information criteria to chose the lag, and then use the lag chosen through the information criteria for Johansen test.

I am not estimating a VAR, but I assume a single equation can be seen as a special case of a VAR, therefore I used the function VARselect in the package vars R to chose the number of lags by minimising the HQ information criterion. Then I used the function ca.jo in the package urca for estimating the Johansen test.

For some countries (e.g. Norway) the test suggests the presence of three cointegrating relationships. Then I realised that for me it is not exactly clear what cointegrating relationships mean, because with three series I cannot understand how the cointegrating relationships could be more than two.

Zero: no cointegration.
One: cointegration with US **or** Eurozone
Two: cointegration with US **and** Eurozone
three: ???

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47404/johansens-pi-is-full-rank-except-variables-are-non-stationary) I read that it should mean that the series are stationary. But the series are not stationary... Unfortunately this question has not been answered in the topic.

Here the summary of the test for Norway:

```
###################### 
# Johansen-Procedure # 
###################### 

Test type: trace statistic , without linear trend and constant in cointegration 

Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1] 9.623907e-03 2.063086e-03 1.629135e-03 5.143053e-19

Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

           test 10pct  5pct  1pct
r <= 2 |  14.02  7.52  9.24 12.97
r <= 1 |  31.77 17.85 19.96 24.60
r = 0  | 114.90 32.00 34.91 41.07

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

              i.l14     US.l14    EMU.l14   constant
i.l14     1.0000000  1.0000000   1.000000  1.0000000
US.l14   -0.9758996  0.5665952   3.931335 -0.7132136
EMU.l14  -0.1144688 -2.0340212   1.127234 -0.8454750
constant -0.5741730 -1.0508460 -12.372963 -6.2086652

Weights W:
(This is the loading matrix)

             i.l14        US.l14       EMU.l14      constant
i.d   -0.004521006 -0.0029241173  0.0001778523  7.053000e-19
US.d  -0.002344370  0.0004143656 -0.0001978083 -5.253666e-20
EMU.d -0.001971539  0.0019213238  0.0001423506 -1.309908e-19
```